# Poisson Distribution answer verification

Tags: probability

```
Let the random variable X represent the length of time (in minutes) 
between calls to a 911 number in a small town.  Assume that the calls 
come into the switchboard according to a Poisson Process at the rate of 
1 call per 20 mins.  What's the probability that the waiting time until 
the arrival of the 1st call after 10am is greater than 15 mins?  Solve 
this problem using Poisson Distribution.
```

(1 call/20 mins)(15 mins) = 3/4 call

P(no calls in the first in 15 mins)

e^-.75(.75)^0/0! = .4724

```
P(no calls in the first 15 mins)
```

is the part I don't get.  Why are we computing for no calls in the 1st 15 mins?

Answer (score 1):

You are computing the probability that there are no calls in the first 15 minutes because the waiting time to the first call is greater than 15 minutes if and only if there are no calls in the first fifteen minutes.

Answer (score 0):

> A box manufacturing facility produces 300 box per hour. The
> probability that an individual box is faulty is 0.01. Calculate the
> probability that in a given hour's production:
>
> Two chips are
> faulty

To find lamina I multiplied `(n)(p)`

```
To find lamina 
0.01*300 = 3
```

Using the Poisson formula to solve for 2 faulty boxes

P(2 chips faulty)

$3^2$ * $e^{-3}$  / 2!

= `.22`

.22 seems very high to me I think I have made a mistake finding the lamina?